# Type props custom header react-navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I created a custom header and the title of this header was extracted from the navigation parameters, however typescript tells me that the property that I passed through the navigation parameters does not exist, could you help me type the header properties or how can I fix this error.

[image]

I tried typing the props directly but I get another more complex error.

these are types for my HomeNavigator

```
export type HomeNavigatorTypes = {
  Home: undefined
  Cart: undefined
  SearchBusiness: undefined
  Delivery: undefined
  CreateAddress: undefined
  BusinessCategory: { category: BusinessCategories }
  Business: undefined
  SearchBusinessItems: undefined
}

.....

const HomeNavigator = createNativeStackNavigator<HomeNavigatorTypes>();
```